# Testing Queries with MongoRepository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, junit

I am trying to run a test on a controller which calls a service 'findByEmailAddress'. This method is being called from a repository 'CustomerRepository' which uses a '@Query' annotation to fetch what is required. When I run the test, it returns a null pointer exception at the service call.

Here's my controller:

```
@Controller
public class CustomerLoginController {

@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;


@RequestMapping(value = "/customer/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createCustomer(@Valid Customer customer, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    Customer customerExists = customerService.findByEmailAddress(customer.getEmail());

    if (customerExists != null) {
        //do some stuff
    }

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        modelAndView.setViewName("view1");
    } else {
        customerService.save(customer);
        modelAndView.addObject("message", "Created!");
        modelAndView.setViewName("view2");
    }

    return modelAndView;

}

}
```

Repository:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {

    @Query(value = "{ 'email' : ?0}")
    Customer findByEmail(String email);

}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Override
    public Customer findByEmailAddress(String email) {
        return customerRepository.findByEmail(email);
   }

}
```

JUnitTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CustomerControllerTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private CustomerLoginController customerLoginController;

    @Mock
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @Mock
    private BindingResult bindingResult;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        customer = mockCustomer();
        customerLoginController = new CustomerLoginController();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnUserToLoginPage_WhenBindingResultHasErrors() throws Exception {
        when(customerService.findByEmailAddress(Constants.CUSTOMER_EMAIL)).thenReturn(customer);
        when(bindingResult.hasErrors()).thenReturn(true);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = customerLoginController.createCustomer(customer, bindingResult);
        assertThat(modelAndView.getViewName(), equalTo("view1"));
    }
}
```

breaks on this line:

```
'Customer customerExists = customerService.findByEmailAddress(customer.getEmail());'
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ashebby.mvc.controller.customer.CustomerLoginController.createCustomer(CustomerLoginController.java:45)
at com.ashebby.mvc.controller.CustomerControllerTests.shouldReturnUserToLoginPage_WhenBindingResultHasErrors(CustomerControllerTests.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Please give the stack of the exception.

Comment: @Aubin updated.

Comment: from the stacktrace the exception is coming from your controller. Because  customerLoginController object is  null. This is because you have not initialized mocks. Do `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in your setUp method

Comment: @pvpkiran I have included the init, but it returns the same exception

Comment: In CustomerLoginController.createCustomer() customerService.save(customer); customerService may be null

Comment: @Aubin that's true, customerService is null, I thought using the @Mock should include it in the test. I have tried `customerService = mock(CustomerService.class)` and still work.